# ReactTable Full text table search not by column

Tags: reactjs

How to write a full table search in ReactTable in `reactjs`?

You can find ReactTable screenshot.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this .

```
handeSeach(e) {
    try {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // Hide the row initially.
        tr[i].style.display = "none";

        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
          cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
          if (cell) {
            if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              tr[i].style.display = "";
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

and input.

```
<input
     className="form-control"
     type="text"
     id="myInput"
     onKeyUp={this.handeSeach}
     placeholder="Search."
     title="Type in a name"
/>
```